# How to install Google.GData SDK to Windows mobile

Tags: c#, wpf, json, windows-phone-8, windows-mobile

Installing google api package with "Install-Package Google.GData.Calendar" thru nuget package console works for installation part properly but, referenses downloaded by nuget is not valid reference file for windows mobile, and creates exception error file not found when running application.

I write this code in function

```
 var feedUrl = "http://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/tr.turkish%23holiday%40group.v.calendar.google.com/public/full";
        var service = new CalendarService("Calendar");

        var qry = new EventQuery(feedUrl);
        qry.StartTime = t1;
        qry.EndTime = t2;

        EventFeed results = service.Query(qry);
```

but program doesn't enter to code, directly creates exception, 
**Error Messages:**

```
Google.GData.Calendar.DLL'. Module was built without symbols.
A first chance exception of type 'System.IO.FileNotFoundException' occurred in Unknown Module.
```

when i search, find out that nuget package is good for desktop, and for mobile need to add google.gdata from source code.

Could you help, how to add google.gdata to WP8 project, i couldn't find the source code of the api's.
And don't know how to install it.

Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the new version of the nu-get package for Windows Phone here.

[Google.Apis.Calendar.v3](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Google.Apis.Calendar.v3/)